# Toad alt + tab Not Working - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, toad

I use windows 10. When I do alt + tab in some windows or another apps there is no problem, they can switch within themselves. But when I open toad i can not use alt + tab, still showing toad.

How can i solve this?
Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem and it started right after a windows update today. OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362

Comment: have you solved, any solution? :)

Comment: Unfortunately none so far. Especially happens when I am inside Excel. Alt just toggles the internal excel menu.